# Understanding proof related to Hungarian algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, proof-explanation, discrete-optimization

I am looking at the Hungarian algorithm's matrix interpretation(and more specifically the trick that is needed for steps 3 and 4 on the Wikipedia page on the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) and trying to figure out the following proof linked to this.

[image: Theorem]

I just have one question about this proof since it is not explained in the text: why is it exactly that the matrix $\boldsymbol{E}$ has $b$ independent zeroes(and $\boldsymbol{D}$ has $a$)? I can't understand this so if someone can explain I would be grateful.

Comment: Because CD is rows and CE is columns.

Comment: @JMP What do you mean by CD and CE?

Comment: See figure (1.9)

Comment: @JMP But you can't multiply them, their dimensions don't fit necessarily. Even if you could how would that prove that the zeroes were in the matrix E or D? please elaborate

Comment: May I know which paper you mentioned is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $a$ rows, and this is indicated by the matrices $C$ and $D$.

There are $b$ columns, and this is indicated by the matrices $C$ and $E$.

They are not multiplied, as the matrix notation used is [augmented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix).

So, $D$ has $a$ zeroes, and $E$ has $b$ zeroes.

A far simpler proof of what the author is trying to prove is that there can be at most $l=\min(m,n)$ zeroes by the pigeon-hole principle (if there are more than $l$, at least one row/column has two zeroes in it), and then supply an example of a matrix with $l$ zeroes, e.g. a diagonal line of zeroes from a corner.

Comment: I understand but why could the zeroes that are being covered not be in in the matrix $\boldsymbol{C}$ and not in $\boldsymbol{D}$ and $\boldsymbol{E}$?

Comment: Because if a zero is in $C$ then it counts towards both $a$ and $b$. The author uses Hall's Theorem to prove this.

Comment: I know this is more than a year old, but for posterity I'd like to point out that the argument in the last paragraph of this answer proves something different than the theorem in the original post. There $A$ is a *fixed* matrix with some pattern of zeroes and we want to choose as many independent zeros as possible, which is a nontrivial problem.